# How to Launch a real install of Ubuntu already on another hard-drive in Windows 7 like a VM

Tags: installation, windows, virtualization

I'm not too familiar with VMs and the like so this may not even be possible.

Here is what I have:

1. A real, full install of Windows 7 on hard drive A.
2. A real, full install of Ubuntu 10.04 on hard drive B.
3. Grub allowing me to select what I want to launch when I start up my computer.

It would be Amazing if I could do one of two things.

- Within Windows 7, launch my real install of ubuntu as if it were a VM.  That means I would get all the installed software, all of the files, and all of the settings.
- Launch a VM copy of ubuntu 10.04 but some how make it use all of the installed software and settings from my real copy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to run 2 fully installed OS's at the same time.  AFAIK, you cannot run two OS's at once without virtualizing one of them.

So here is what I found on moving an OS from a hard drive to a virtual machine

> Convert your Computer into a Virtual
>   Machine
>
> There's a new
>   utility from Microsoft that makes it
>   both simple and free to convert an
>   existing installation of Windows into
>   a virtual machine ready to run on any
>   other computer.
>
> Microsoft’s Sysinternals team has
>   released a simple application called
>   [Disk2vhd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx), that lets you easily migrate
>   an existing computer to a virtualized
>   hard drive (VHD). It's a tiny utility
>   doesn't even require instillation.
>   Create Virtual Hard Disks with
>   Disk2VHD
>
> When you run Disk2vhd, it will
>   immediately show you all the drives
>   and partitions on your computer that
>   it can migrate to a VHD.  Simply
>   select a drive that you wish to create
>   a VHD file from and click “Create.”
>   Disk2vhd will convert the hard drive
>   into a VHD file even if the computer
>   /drive is currently in use.
>
> When the Virtual Machine VHD file is
>   created, you can run it in any desktop
>   virtualization program including the
>   free [Windows Virtual PC](http://www.labnol.org/software/create-virtual-machine-of-existing-computer/10510/), [Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org/),
>   or [VMware Player](http://www.vmware.com/). You can also mount
>   the virtual machine as a standard hard
>   drive in Windows 7, and can even boot
>   from it if your computer is running
>   Windows 7 Ultimate.
>
> You may use Disk2vhd to create virtual
>   machines of your Windows XP, Windows
>   Server 2003, Windows Vista and higher
>   machines, including x64 systems. Usage
>   Scenario
>
> Let's say you have a computer that is
>   already running all the software
>   programs you frequently use, but you
>   now want to move to a new computer or
>   upgrade your operating system. You can
>   then consider creating a virtual
>   machine of your old machine using the
>   Microsoft utility and this will help
>   you use all your favorite programs
>   (with the same settings) on the new
>   machine.
>
> You can also use virtualization to
>   create a ghost image of your hard
>   drive in a single file and this will
>   be handy in the event of a disk
>   failure.
>
> Disk2vhd is an useful tool that will
>   make it much easier for you to enjoy
>   the benefits of virtualization without
>   being too technical.

From [labnol.org](http://www.labnol.org/software/create-virtual-machine-of-existing-computer/10510/)

Hope this helps.